# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 21 requested, with a size of 21

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I try to log the name & age indexes and get an error of them being out of range and I don't know why.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Users"
            , MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name " +
            "VARCHAR, age INT(3))");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('Nick', 28)");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('Alon', 25)");

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users", null);

    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    int ageIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("age");

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
        Log.i("name", cursor.getString(nameIndex));
        Log.i("age", cursor.getString(ageIndex));
        Toast.makeText(this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

}

I tried looking for solutions here in stackoverflow but did not find anything
it

I get the error as the title says

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            String age = cursor.getString(ageIndex );

        }while (result.moveToNext());
    }
```

You can read [this document](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) to add sqlite in a good way.

Comment: I found a solution using a try-catch block wrapping the entire code. does it have the same effect? because it works.